# Base de datos portable JS

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos

Hola amigos tengo una duda, lo que pasa es que un cliente quiere una app para poder insertar leer, editar datos, pero el unico requisito es que eso se debe manejar desde una USB ya que haci lo pide el cliente, mi solucion es crear una app con electron, y un archivo json como db, investigando un poco me dicen que al tener muchos datos el archivo json, se volvera lenta la app(las cosultas), quisiera saber que alternativas hay, para que el usuario solo ejecute la aplicacion y ya pueda realizar todas esas tareas, para asi evitar tener que decirle que debe instalar algun motor de db, luego correrlo, etc..
O si solo con el archvo json seria suficiente.
La appp manejara entre 500 y 1000 datos
Muchas gracias

Comment: [Esto puede ser muy interesante para ti](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa?hl=es). Puede que [`IndexDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/IndexedDB-840092-dup/Usando_IndexedDB) sería una solución óptima en este caso. El punto de interrogación sería pasar la BD al USB, quizá haya alguna forma con esas tecnologías, habría que averiguarlo.

Comment: Estaba penasando lo mismo, es mas ahora estoy leyendo algo sobre eso, voy haber que puedo hacer

Comment: Una buena opción también sería [`Firebase`](https://firebase.google.com). Puedes programar lo que quieras desde ahí, incluso una elegante app para el cliente que le funcione desde el móvil, tablet, PC... Inicio de sesión, áreas protegidas, etc, etc. Si el cliente prueba Firebase es muy posible que hasta se olvide del USB, aunque una sincronización de la base de datos con un dispositivo USB no debería ser demasiado complicada.

Comment: lo que pasa es que un requisito es que sea solo guardado en la usb, nada de internet :(

Comment: una opción puede ser [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html)

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal Al usar sqlLite no hay nesecidad de instalar nada?

Comment: @DiegoMonsalve en teoría no, pegale una mirada a [esta librería](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/) que posiblemente solucione tu problema